# What are the common ways to test sensors working properly

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I'm going to create an app which uses sensors in a smartphone. Before doing this job, I also want to test the sensors of the smartphone so that I can evaluate their correctness. What are the common ways to achieve that? I'm going to use phone's accelerometer sensor. But I also wonder about other sensors too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a level, verify that a surface is flat.  Place the phone on the surface, and ensure that there is a 1g reading in one direction and zero in the others. This can be done in the other two directions as well to ensure they are reading 1g from gravity, but you will need a holder that keeps it at exactly a right angle with the surface (or alternatively, set on the floor with the back of the phone against a wall once you know the wall and floor are level).